# D3.js - Donut chart click event with multiple rings

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, charts

I have been trying to implement D3.js donut with multiple rings. But, the problem is with click event as it works fine with click on first ring but, show weird behavior while clicking on the second ring. Also it shows some weird problems with mousehover as well.

> {"metaData":null,
>   "data":{graphDetails":[{"displayName":"MUW","name":"DEF","score":5},{"displayName":"ABC","name":"ABCD","score":15},{"displayName":"DEFA","name":"DEF","score":35}],"graphOneDetails":[{"displayName":"D1","name":"D1","score":11},{"displayName":"D2","name":"D2","score":25},{"displayName":"D3","name":"D3","score":22}]},"success":true}

```
  //Define arc ranges
    var arcText = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, .3);
    // Determine size of arcs
    var arc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius - 75).outerRadius(radius - 25);
    var arc_2= d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius - 25).outerRadius(radius);
    //Create the donut pie chart layout
    d3.layout.pie().value(function(d){
    return d["score"];
    }).sort(null);
    //Append SVG attributes and append g to the SVG
    d3.select("#donut-chart")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height",height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate("+radius+","+radius+")");

    //Define Inner Circle
    svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx",0)
    .attr("cy",0)
    .attr("r",280)
    .attr("fill","#fff");
    //Calculate SVG paths and fill in the colors
    var div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","tooltip")
    .style("opactiy",0);
    // Append First Chart
    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc").data(pie($scope.categories))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class","arc")
    .on("click",function(d, i){
        alert(d.data.name)
    }).on("mouseover",function(d){
        alert(d.data.name);
    }).on("mouseout",function(d){
       alert(d.data.name);
    });
   g.append("path")
    .attr("d",arc)
    .attr("fill","#024");
   g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d){
        return "translate("+arc.centroid(d)+")";
    }).attr("dy",".35em")
    .style("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("fill","#fff")
    .text(function (d,i){
        return d.data.displayName
    });
   g.selectAll(".arc text").call(wrap.arcText.rangeBand());
   //Append Second Chart
   g.data(pie($scope.divisions)).append("path")
    .attr("d",arc_2)
    .attr("fill","#eee");
   g.on("click, function(d,i){
    alert(d.data.name);
   }).on("mouseover", function(d){
    alert(d.data.name);
   });
   //Append text to second chart
      g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d){
        return "translate("+arc_2.centroid(d)+")";
    }).attr("dy",".35em")
    .style("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("fill","#fff")
    .text(function (d,i){
        return d.data.displayName
    });
   g.selectAll(".arc text").call(wrap.arcText.rangeBand());
```

In initial state it works fine, but, when I click one chart it displays the data correctly. And when I click inner chart and updates my json to

> {"metaData":null,
>   "data":{graphDetails":[{"displayName":"MUW","name":"DEF","score":5},{"displayName":"DEFA","name":"DEF","score":35}],"graphOneDetails":[{"displayName":"D1","name":"D1","score":11},{"displayName":"D3","name":"D3","score":22}]},"success":true}

Then it display inner chart as a full donut but, the outer chart comes as an arc instead of full donut. Same problem is happening with the mouse over as while I am hovering over the second chart each and everything comes correctly as a tool-tip. (I didn't include the code of tool-tip). But, I mouse over on ABC and returns me DEFA. So, I think there must be something related to the way I have appended these two arcs.

**EDIT 1**
Created the JSFidle, with my dataset and it's not showing anything

http://jsfiddle.net/pcr3ogt4/

Comment: please post a minimum working fiddle ... the scriplet you have posted is inconclusive :(

Comment: In my case I had added two mouse event handlers on arcs,  drag and click. The drag was only calling the event handler for outer circle. Click called event handler for all circles respectively. So when I clicked on outer circle it worked fine, What was causing the problem was the drag event handler was also called when clicked event fired from inner circle. This was calling, the event handler for both outer circle(drag) and inner circle(click). I had to fix this by setting the drag distance to more than zero.